# How do I select from two variables in Unity

Tags: arrays, unity-game-engine

I have two scores

A = 0 
B = 0

I want to randomly pick one and add 7 to it.

I believe I have to do an array, but can't figure that out.

I also believe I need to do a random.range, but because I can't figure out the array I can't get beyond this step.

I would also like to set Which every team scored to "teamScored"

code:

```
public float A = 0;
public float B = 0;

public float [] scores = {A,B};

public float teamScore=??;

public void Start{
    teamScored = scores(Random.Range(0,2));
    teamScored +7;

}
```

I know this is broken, but this is how I see it suppose to be working in my head.

Comment: Because `A` and `B` are value types (`floats`) making an array that contains them will copy their values into the array. This means `A` and `B` won't change when you change the array's copies. I suggest removing `A` and `B` entirely and directly using the array. If you must have `A` and `B`, use properties instead like `public float A { get { return scores[0]; } }`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int A = 0;
public int B = 0;

public int[] scores = {A,B};

public void Start{  
int teamScored = Random.Range(0,2);
scores[teamScored] += 7;
}
```

Comment: It says I need to use Set or Get the teamScored.  Do I have to do this with the other scores as they will be updated all the time as well?